# Kivy Android Build Weakly Referenced Object No Longer Exists

Tags: python, android, kivy

My kivy App runs fine on the Kivy emulator, after porting to Android I face the above error.

```
I/python: [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
I/python: [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
I/python: [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
I/python:  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python:    File "/Users/martinprater/PycharmProjects/kivy/build/bdist.android-armeabi-v7a/main.py", line 1014, in <module>
I/python:    File "/Users/martinprater/.python-for-android/build/python-installs/bdisttest/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
I/python:    File "/Users/martinprater/.python-for-android/build/python-installs/bdisttest/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
I/python:    File "/Users/martinprater/.python-for-android/build/python-installs/bdisttest/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
I/python:    File "/Users/martinprater/.python-for-android/build/python-installs/bdisttest/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
I/python:    File "/Users/martinprater/.python-for-android/build/python-installs/bdisttest/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
I/python:    File "/Users/martinprater/.python-for-android/build/python-installs/bdisttest/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
I/python:    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
I/python:    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
I/python:    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
I/python:    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 154, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
I/python:    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 86, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.get_callback
I/python:    File "/Users/martinprater/.python-for-android/build/python-installs/bdisttest/kivy/weakmethod.py", line 56, in is_dead
I/python:  ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
I/python: Python for android ended.
E/libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSt3__112system_errorE: mutex lock failed: Device or resource busy
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 22565 (mple.stopwining), pid 22565 (mple.stopwining)
```

I could not manage to get hostpython 3.7.5 to work with Buildozer. While this occurs at various points I can reproduce it by just adding or deleting an image to a button.

```
<MainScreen>:

    __usernamebtn_id: [usernamebtn.__self__]
    __usernameico_id: [usernameico.__self__]
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'some.jpg'
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 0.08

            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: tr('Some Text')
                    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                    markup: True
                    font_size: 50
                    size_hint_x: 0.9

                Button:
                    id: usernamebtn
                    size_hint_x: 0.15
                    disabled: True
                    text: ''
                    font_size: 20
                    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                Button:
                    id: usernameico
                    size_hint_x: 0.05
                    on_release:
                        root.manager.current = 'UserScreen'
#commenting this out, the error no longer occurs, the moment I include the image, the reference issue happens
                    Image:
                        source: "username.png"
                        center_x: self.parent.center_x
                        center_y: self.parent.center_y
```

Mainscreen code is reduced to:

```
def on_enter(self):
    print('enter main screen')
    return
```

It may be a coincidence with image due to memory consumption, but how can I locate the exact weak reference.

I have tried kivy 1 and kivy 2 (v2.0.0rc2), with the same result.
Any help warmly appreciated.
Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Your indentation shows the `Image` as a child of a `Button`, is that your intention?

Comment: Yes, I am using the image as an icon for the button.

Comment: Not sure what that means, but to use an image as the background of a `Button`, you would normally use `background_normal: 'username.png'`.

Comment: Changing to this method my mini example works, but applying it to the whole code still breaks the same as before. I now can no longer see the text in my button though. I have treated all ids as mentioned in the code sample to ensure gc does not collect them. Any suggestion how to find the culprit. It dies moving from login screen to main screen, before I get control in the main screen.

Comment: Are you using `Buildozer`?

Comment: I am using Buildozer for the initial package and then update using p4a and setup.py to add my images and language files.